# Remove ImageView border in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I am making an app that uses cards to display information, and I want to have an image on the left side of the card. The problem I'm having is that the ImageView I'm inserting at the left side is being padded on all sides for some reason.

After doing some searching online, I found many posts on stackoverflow that were asking the same question, and all of them were told to use this code fix their issue:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

and to simply add this within their ImageView in the xml. I tried this, but the padding remains. I have set the background color of the image view to lime green to illustrate the padded areas.

Here is my XML code for the card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drinkImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:gravity="left"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/drinkName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drinkImage"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/drinkDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/drinkName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drinkImage"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is what I'm getting on my screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVaR4.png

[image]

Comment: have you tried to play with `android:scaleType` attribute for your image view? `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` might do the trick

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_width="100dp"` and
            `android:layout_height="100dp"` instead of `match_parent`. And try to remove `android:foreground` also?

Comment: Setting `android:scaleType` to different values is not changing anything, neither is manually setting the layout width and height, even to values higher than 100dp. I'm not really sure what to do with `android:foreground`

Comment: Is the border actually part of the image? i.e. a strip of transparent pixels around the edge of the PNG.

Comment: Nope, I made sure of that, and have tried multiple different pictures, I get the same border around it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turns out I was adding an image asset to the project by right-clicking drawable/ and clicking new->Image Asset. what I didn't realize this does is actually crop and resize the image, as I obviously had no idea the proper usage of the image asset creator.

To add the .PNG files to the project, I simply copied the image files from Finder (the Mac equivalent of Windows Explorer) and pasted them into the drawables folder in Android Studio and everything works out perfectly. Such a noob mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The green "border" is not a border, is the background of the `ImageView` set by you with `android:background="#00FF00"`. Over the `ImageView` your image is drawn. The images ratio does not fit with `ImageView`s width and height or the image width or height is less then the `ImageView`s width or height. The default behaviour of `ImageView` in this case is to center the image in the `ImageView`. Therefore you see the space. You can specify the behavior by using `android:scaleType` . See the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) . Otherwise you can adjust the `ImageView`s width and height to match the one of the image.

Update:
oh I'm sorry, I haven't noticed that you are using `CardView`:

According to the docs, this as designed:

> Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms before L, CardView does not clip its children that intersect with rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to avoid such intersection (See setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean) to change this behavior).

See [the `CardView` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) for more info.

Comment: My problem is that I want the image to fill up the entire ImageView, there shouldn't be an extra background border other than the image. The green was something I put in there to illustrate the area I want to be filled with the image, i.e. not left empty.

Comment: The image I'm using is a very large one, I'm not sure why it's making it smaller and then deliberately adding a border around it

Comment: Is the aspect ratio (width :  height)  of both `ImageView` and  your raw image the same? Set `android:scaleType="fitXY"` (fills the ImageView completely in width and height, but the image will be stretched an may look strange) or use  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` (image will be cropped so that it will fit in `ImageView` but some pixels of the image will not be displayed as they are cropped (cut)  to fill ImageViews width and height.

Comment: That's interesting that android does that, but the documentation states:

"Setting this value on API 21 and above does not have any effect unless you have enabled compatibility padding."

I'm using API 21, so this shouldn't be happening in the first place, could it have something to do with the fact that I'm using an AppCompat theme? If not, how do enable/disable compatibility padding?